# How do I import svg images with passed names via props in Astro?

Tags: image, svg, astrojs

I have a component where I assign title, description and image from a prop. I am using a JSON Array to iterate over to create multiple instance of this component and add images.

I have two problems while using images in Astro -

Problem 1 : Astro ignores image on build when using images with direct path without import syntax.

```
<img 
    class="spec-logo linear-gradient"
    src={'../assets/specifications/'+imgname+'.svg'} 
    alt={title}/>
```

So I read other SF posts and came to know that import syntax mitigate this problem.

Now I have other problems because I dont know how to dynamically import the images using import syntax

Problem 2 : Inline import syntax isn't working as [explained here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astrojs/image#examples) -

I have used img tag

```
<img 
  class="spec-logo linear-gradient"
  src={import('../assets/specifications/battery.svg')} <---
  alt={title}/>

  error -- 
  'Promise<typeof import("*.svg")>' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Another solution I tried was this -

```
<Fragment set:html={import('../assets/specifications/battery.svg?raw')} />
```

This is rendering [object object]

The third and final solution I tired is this -

```
<svg class="w-6 h-6">
            <use xlink:href={import('../assets/specifications/battery.svg') + '#icon-id'}></use>
          </svg>
```

None of the above is working -

Comment: the problem is that astro does image resizing etc at build-time, so a string is not enough. the best solution depends a bit on where the image url is originally coming from. an external api like a cms or the file is contained in your repo? One solution is [collections](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#images-in-content-collections).

Comment: @mb21 thanks. I am loading images from assets folder. I am not loading from any external url.

Comment: Then definitely easiest to just import all of them individually and construct the array or whatever you need manually. Or yes, otherwise use astro collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found after reading [this blog](https://ellodave.dev/blog/article/using-svgs-as-astro-components-and-inline-css/) is below -

```
interface Props {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgsrc: string;
} 

const { title, description, imgsrc } = Astro.props as Props;
const { default: innerHTML } = await import(`../assets/specifications/${imgsrc}.svg?raw`);


<span class="card-title">{title}</span> 
<span class="card-value linear-gradient">{description}</span>
<Fragment set:html={innerHTML} class="spec-logo"/>
```

**Edit 1**: It seems it worked fine but as soon as I build the project and checked the preview, all these images were missing. The problem still persists as these images are not getting include on build.

**Edit 2**: I think build wasn't done properly. After closing the IDE and rebuilding fixed the issue.